# Function is meant to be non-destructive but it is modifying my variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code which sets `special` to run a function `convertSpecial` which will replace the apostrophe in `array1` with a provided character. In this case, a space. Since the replacing character is a space, it will split that element into two then flatten the array. It will then check to see if any element in `special` matches any element in `array2`. This will return false. It will then replace the apostrophe with no character at all and recheck against array2.

The idea behind `convertSpecial` and the variable `special` is that it should be non-destructive to `array1`, but this isn't happening as you can see:

```js
var array1 = ["o'hara"];
var array2 = ["ohara"];
var special = '';

function convertSpecial(a,b,c) {
 var aCopy = a;
 for (let i = 0; i < aCopy.length; i++) {
  if (aCopy[i].includes(b)) {
   if (c == '') {       
    aCopy[i] = aCopy[i].replace(b,c);
   } else {
    aCopy[i] = aCopy[i].replace(b,c).split(' ');
      
    aCopy = aCopy.flat();
   }
  }    
 }
   
 return aCopy;
}
  
console.log('array1 1 = '+array1); // returns array1 1 = o'hara as expected

special = convertSpecial(array1,"'"," ");
    
console.log('array1 2 = '+array1); // returns array1 2 = o,hara THIS SHOULD NOT HAVE BEEN MODIFIED
console.log('special 1 = '+special); //returns special 2 = o,hara as expected

if (array2.some(v => special.includes(v)) == true) {
console.log('array1 3 = '+array1); // ignored as expected

array1 = specialDECln;
} else {
console.log('array1 4 = '+array1); //returns array1 4 = o,hara  THIS SHOULD NOT HAVE BEEN MODIFIED

special = convertSpecial(array1,"'","");
  
console.log('array1 5 = '+array1); //returns array1 5 = o,hara THIS SHOULD NOT HAVE BEEN MODIFIED
console.log('special 2= '+special); //returns special 2 = o,hara should be ohara
     
if (array2.some(v => special.includes(v)) == true) {
 array1 = special;
} 
}
      
console.log(array2 == special);   //returns false, should be true because expected ohara = ohara
```

Everything works as it should, EXCEPT `array1` is being modified when it shouldn't be at all. Since it gets modified, `special` gets set to an incorrect value.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: `a[i] = a[i].replace(b,c);` <-- um, you are modifying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clone that array in order to avoid mutation.  There are a lot of ways for doing that, an alternative is using the Spread-syntax as follow:

```
let result = [...a]; // This creates a new array with the index-values from array a.
```

```js
var array1 = ["o'hara"];
var special = ''

console.log("array1 = " + array1); // returns array1 = o'hara as expected

function convertSpecial(a, b, c) { // a = array, b = character to replace, c = character to replace with
  let result = [...a];
  for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    if (result[i].includes(b)) {
      if (c == '') {
        result[i] = result[i].replace(b, c);
      } else {
        result[i] = result[i].replace(b, c).split(' ');
        result = result.flat();
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}

special = convertSpecial(array1, "'", " ");

console.log("array1 = " + array1); // returns array1 = o, hara but it should be o'hara

console.log("special = " + special); // returns special = o, hara as expected
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to duplicate the array first:

```js
var array1 = ["o'hara"];
var special = ''

console.log("array1 = " + array1); // returns array1 = o'hara as expected

function convertSpecial(a, b, c) { // a = array, b = character to replace, c = character to replace with
  var aCopy = a.slice();
  for (let i = 0; i < aCopy.length; i++) {
    if (aCopy[i].includes(b)) {
      if (c == '') {
        aCopy[i] = aCopy[i].replace(b, c);
      } else {
        aCopy[i] = aCopy[i].replace(b, c).split(' ');

        aCopy = aCopy.flat();
      }
    }
  }

  return aCopy;
}

special = convertSpecial(array1, "'", " ");

console.log("array1 = " + array1); // returns array1 = o, hara but it should be o'hara

console.log("special = " + special); // returns special = o, hara as expected
```

Comment: this is still modifying array1 for some reason... see updated answer

Comment: What do you mean? `arrray1` is still `o'hara`.

Comment: look at my question, array1 winds up getting modified after running the function.

Comment: Erm, no...it's still `o'hara` - look at my answer.

Comment: all I can say is that when you press run on my question, that's not what shows.

Comment: Yes - because your question doesn't have my solve - my answer does have the solve.